# Highlighting the cluster of scatterplot using highcharter in R

Tags: r, highcharts, scatter-plot

I'm using highcharter pkg in R for drawing a scatter plot.

```
library(highcharter) 
# Load data
data("mtcars")
df <- mtcars
# Convert cyl as a grouping variable
df$cyl <- as.factor(df$cyl)
# Inspect the data
head(df[, c("wt", "mpg", "cyl", "qsec")], 4)
df %>% 
  hchart(
    'scatter', hcaes(x = wt, y = mpg, size = qsec, group = cyl),
    maxSize = "10%"
  )
```

There is a cool feature in the highcharter pkg that when you hover over a cluster in the legend, the points for that specific cluster stand out from the rest of the clusters.
[image]
I don't know how I can control this feature programmatically. I want to have this view not by hovering over to the cluster but by selecting cluster from the code (maybe by defining the cluster group) and it can give me highlighted view like the picture above.

I checked [highcharts documentations](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.scatter) but I couldn't get any clue.

appreciate it

Comment: So you want the code to do that?

Comment: [hover over legend to highlight points](https://www.highcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=15465)

Comment: Do you want to highlight when you hover the legend items, like in this [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/scatter)?

Comment: @SebastianHajdus I want the code to highlight like the demo (maybe by passing a cluster list that I wanna highlight). Not by hovering over my mouse

Comment: Doesn't answer your question, but a workaround to consider if time is pressing is to assign colors to your series manually, taking advantage of the ability to use `rgba()` color rather than hex.  This will let you specify alpha, and control the opacity of the colors you're using.  Make all colors besides the highlighted more transparent, and you're ready to generate images with the highlighting effect you're after!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your other answerer implied, it may be best to simply alter the opacity by series (each color is a different series here).

To understand the meaning of `c(.25, 1, .25)` for `opacity` in the code below, consider what is controlling the colors.

```
unique(mtcars$cyl)
# [1] 6 4 8   # assume that HC sorted these
```

So the first opacity value is assigned to points where `cyl == 4`.

```
df %>% 
  hchart(opacity = c(.25, 1, .25), 
    'scatter', hcaes(x = wt, y = mpg, size = qsec, group = cyl),
    maxSize = "10%"
  )
```

[image]

You can assign the *state*. Manually changing the state doesn't set the styles associated with the state, though.

In this code, I've set those points where `cyl == 6` to the state of `hover`. However, I didn't touch the other traces. Note that this requires the assignment of an `id` in the `hchart` call.

```
df %>% 
  hchart('scatter', hcaes(x = wt, y = mpg, size = qsec, group = cyl,
                          id = cyl), maxSize = "10%") %>% 
  htmlwidgets::onRender(
    "function(el) {
       var chart = $('#' + el.id).highcharts();
       var haloMe = chart.get('6');
       haloMe.setState('hover');
     }")
```

If you look closely at the image, the first point in `6` has that halo effect. Other than that, you can't see any difference in the points. (You may notice this is a bit *glitchy*, as well.)

[image]

Changing all series' states doesn't help, either. In this version, I've set one series to 'hover' and the other 2 to 'inactive'. There's no difference. When rendered in your browser, you can check the state and see that they are set as shown in this code.

```
df %>% 
  hchart('scatter', hcaes(x = wt, y = mpg, size = qsec, group = cyl,
                          id = cyl), maxSize = "10%") %>% 
  htmlwidgets::onRender(
    "function(el) {
       var chart = $('#' + el.id).highcharts();
       var haloMe = chart.get('6');
       haloMe.setState('hover');
       var inact4 = chart.get('4');
       var inact8 = chart.get('8');
       inact4.setState('inactive');
       inact8.setState('inactive');
     }")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to set [opacity](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.scatter.opacity) for each series, from the range 0,1 up to 1 for more visibility.

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'scatter',
    zoomType: 'xy'
  },
  legend: {
    enabled: true
  },
  plotOptions: {
    scatter: {
      marker: {
        radius: 12.5,
        symbol: 'circle',
        states: {
          hover: {
            enabled: false,
            lineColor: 'rgb(100,100,100)'
          }
        }
      },
      states: {
        hover: {
          marker: {
            enabled: false
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  tooltip: {
    pointFormat: 'Name: {point.name}'
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'male',
    opacity: 1,
    data: [
      ['Alexander', 8, 7],
      ['Brage', 8, 7],
      ['Emil', 11, 3],
      ['Henrik', 12, 2],
      ['Isak', 9, 4],
      ['Johannes', 9, 4],
      ['Lucas', 7, 10],
      ['Magnus', 8, 7],
      ['Odin', 6, 12],
      ['Ola', 6, 12],
      ['Olav', 6, 12],
      ['Oliver', 7, 10],
      ['Oskar', 9, 4],
      ['Sverre', 6, 12],
      ['Tobias', 6, 12],
      ['William', 13, 1]
    ],

  }, {
    name: 'female',
    opacity: 0.1,
    data: [
      ['Ada', 7, 7],
      ['Alma', 6, 13],
      ['Amalie', 6, 13],
      ['Ella', 9, 2],
      ['Frida', 8, 5],
      ['Hannah', 7, 7],
      ['Helene', 7, 7],
      ['Ingrid', 7, 7],
      ['Maja', 8, 5],
      ['Maria', 6, 13],
      ['Nora', 9, 2],
      ['Sara', 9, 2],
      ['Sofia', 7, 7],
      ['Sofie', 7, 7],
      ['Tiril', 6, 13],
      ['Vilde', 10, 1]
    ]
  }]
});
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/tr07n9bh/)